# Side by side view of PDF files in UWP apps

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need the pdf viewer side by side of my app, so that i will be able to view the pdf generated when any changes made in app. In windows 8.1 app the PDF is opened using Reader app and by default it opens PDF side by side.

But the case in Win10 is not the same. In win 10 the reader app is opened seperately pushing back the app screen.Is there any similar viewer as like in win 8.1

Below image is from windows 8.1 app

[image]

Comment: Any relative code snippet? What's the feature you are developing? What's the reader app?

Comment: Code snippet has nothing to do with my problem. the problem is with pdf viewer. Reader app is the app by Microsoft Corporation which is for opening PDF & other documents

Comment: In the above image left side is my app screen and right side is the reader app. When pdf is opened from app the reader app is launched by splitting the screens equally as you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to open PDF files inside the app

As usual I opened PDF from files as storage file.

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/pdffile.pdf"));
Windows.Data.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = await Windows.Data.Pdf.PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
Load(doc);
```

Now the PDF document is read page by page as BitmapImage and added to a list.

```
public async void Load(PdfDocument pdfDoc)
    {
        PdfPages.Clear();

        for (uint i = 0; i < pdfDoc.PageCount; i++)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

            var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);

            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);
                await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            }

            PdfPages.Add(image);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> PdfDocPages
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
```

Binding the ObservableCollection to the ItemsControl we can view the PDF as images.

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" Background="DarkGray" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PdfDocPages, ElementName=pageRoot}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Margin="0 2" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```